# Best way to do fetching of row with attribute that is not referenced to other attribute in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have 1 entity called Project with attribute of:

- ProjectNo
- ProjectNoRef (reference to ProjectNo attribute)
- Month

Example:

```
===================================
| ProjectNo | ProjectNoRef| Month |
===================================
|   Proj01  |     NULL    |   1   |
|   Proj02  |     NULL    |   1   |
|   Proj03  |     NULL    |   1   |
|   Proj04  |     NULL    |   1   |
|   Proj05  |    Proj01   |   2   |
|   Proj06  |     NULL    |   2   |
===================================
```

I want to fetch all projects within certain month that is not referenced to other project.

From above example, it will result 3 for month 1 and 2 for month 2.

What is the best way to do this in Core Data? I don't want to do double fetching as there will be thousand projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object graph should include an optional relationship between a project and its sub-project(s).

Then it becomes a simple matter to fetch all projects which don't have sub-projects, and group the results by month.

Comment: The reason I have `ProjectNoRef` as an attribute is because I only care the String value of `ProjectNo`.  Will Core Data fetch all the attributes of other if I change it to relationship?

Comment: Yes.  By default, the related project exists as a fault (placeholder object).  Core Data will automatically retrieve its data when you access the referenced object's attribute(s).  It is also possible to pre-fetch related entities.

Comment: By the way, how can I fetch it if I change it to relationship? I want to fetch all projects that are not referenced to all projects, not don't have sub-projects :)

Comment: As I understand, you want to fetch all projects that are not referenced by another project.  Since you didn't specify what that reference really meant, I just described it as a sub-project.  Regardless, you can specify that its count of projects that reference it is 0.